# Electricity and electric fields equations

Tags: electricity

Whats the difference or relationship of $q$ between the equations $E=F/q$, $v=W/Q$ and $Q =ne$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It just refers to charge and there is no significant difference

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on the context you use it: if I understand well the expressions, in the first one "q" means a reference charge that you use to measure the intensity of the force's field in the space; in the other expressions it's just net charge of the system.